# Square root in Ruby with more precision than BigDecimal.sqrt?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision

I thought that the purpose of Ruby's BigDecimal class is that it is <strike>infinitely</strike> arbitrarily precise at the cost of speed. Wrong:

```
> BigDecimal(4).sqrt(4)
=> #<BigDecimal:906602c,'0.1999999999 9999999998 66602351E1',36(36)>
> BigDecimal(4).sqrt(11)
=> #<BigDecimal:9e36850,'0.2E1',9(45)>
```

First, `sqrt` should work without a parameter, at least by the documentation. Second, if that parameter is the precision, 4 should suffice for this operation (or at least I shouldn't know that 11 digit precision is OK).

The last thing I want is to reinvent the wheel, and create some 'arbitrarily precise squaring library' of my own.

Questions:

- Is it possible to set parameters to a BigDecimal instance so the above does not happen? (meaning: It gives back proper result at low precision)
- Is there any detailed info on the BigDecimal object (what those numbers are after the value)?

System: Debian, 32-bit, ruby 1.9.3p125

Comment: What's your question again? (I understand the problem you're basically using this question to complain about, but I'm not sure what help you're looking for from Stack Overflow.) Just _"where are [the docs on BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)"_?

Comment: To make "infinitely precise" sqrt you need infinite memory. Guess you don't have it. What's wrong then?

Comment: @VictorMoroz I have lots of memory, but to my dismay I couldn't test all of it as I run into this problem that the square root of 4 is not 2, in an arbitrarily precise library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big decimal docs for [inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-inspect) describe what that output means.

Regarding the documentation for `sqrt` that seems to be a documentation bug - see http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5267

As for the output you're getting, I'm not sure - I get 0.2E1 in both cases.

Comment: In _arbitrary precision_ what is the meaning of the *maximum precision* in case of a repeating, non-terminating number like 1.0/3.0? I thought that _precision_ is something set by me as  arbitrary precision should not have pre-set hard limits.

Comment: arbitrary is not the same as infinite. You can ask for any amount of precision (10 significant digit, 100, etc.) but you do need to pick ahead of time

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote: "*precision is something set by me*". However BigDecimal seems to pick some precision value by itself.